# How do I get Trailing 12 Months for a specific month but dynamic year?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm using January as an example to try and simplify this.

Here is the original query:

```
SELECT 
  ASIN
, SUM(CASE WHEN search_date BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -12, '2022-01-31')  AND '2022-01-31' THEN all_searches ELSE 0 END) jan_ttm_searches
FROM search_table 
WHERE search_date BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -12, '2022-01-31')  AND '2022-01-31'
GROUP BY 1;
```

What I'm trying to do is take this query and modify it to run based on the current year instead of a static date. So, for example:

- Running this right now (Dec 2022) should give me TTM for Jan 2022
- Running this in Jan 2023 should give me TTM from Jan 2022 (because the month is incomplete)
- Running this in Feb 2023 should give me TTM from Jan 2023 (because Jan has now passed and we have complete data)

I need '2022-01-31' to adapt to the current date instead of being static.

ASIN is a number/character identifier. Search Date example is 2022-11-24 00:00:00. All_searches is the number of searches for that asin on that date.

I've tried to put an EXTRACT in the CASE WHEN, but that errored for nested aggregates.

```
CASE WHEN search_date between dateadd(month, -12, TRUNC(MAX(search_date)))) AND TRUNC(MAX(search_date)) 
            AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM search_date) = 1 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM search_date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)
```

I tried using RUN_DATE, which gets me TTM from the current date but not from January.

```
case when search_date BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}', 'YYYYMMDD'), -12) AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}', 'YYYYMMDD') then all_searches else 0 end
```

I tried googling similar issues but couldn't find a solution that worked for what I'm trying to do.

The query is going to Redshift. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edited to add: Desired output is one column with ASIN and one column with the total number of searches for that month. The original query works except for the static date. This is intended to run on a schedule every month and needs to be reactive to the current year/month.

Comment: Redshift is not "based" on Postgres. Its SQL parser was taken from a very, very old Postgres version. The rest is completely different. Plus: the query as written won't work on Postgres at all (it has no `dateadd()` or `add_months()` function

Comment: Apologies for saying it was based on Postgres; I'm new to SQL and was referring to an Amazon AWS page that states: "Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL. Amazon Redshift and PostgreSQL have a number of very important differences that you must be aware of as you design and develop your data warehouse applications."

Answer (score 0):

I think you have answered your own question.  You cannot nest aggregates but you can compute the MAX() in a subquery.  You can do this a couple of ways:

1. Compute the max in a CTE or subquery and use this result for the CASE statement.  You can do this with the MAX() window function so that all the originals rows will be present for the CASE statement.
2. Compute the MAX() and CROSS JOIN this single value to original table.

#1 is likely better for large tables as it only needs to scan the table once while #2 scans the table twice.

==========================================================

Since you haven't provided any data or expected results I've made up some data and a process to achieve something like what you are looking for.  This is likely not exact but will show how to generate the date limit you are looking for from the source table.

I also changed things so that the SQL will run in Postgres as well as Redshift so you use a sql fiddle to play with the code if you like.

Set up data:

```
create table test (
  ASIN varchar(16),
  search_date date,
  all_searches int
);

insert into test values
  ('abc', '2021-01-15', 5),
  ('def', '2021-02-15', 4),
  ('ghi', '2021-03-15', 3),
  ('jkl', '2021-04-15', 2),
  ('mno', '2021-05-15', 1),
  ('abc', '2021-06-15', 10),
  ('def', '2021-07-15', 11),
  ('ghi', '2021-08-15', 12),
  ('jkl', '2021-09-15', 13),
  ('mno', '2021-10-15', 14),
  ('abc', '2022-01-15', 9),
  ('def', '2022-01-15', 8),
  ('ghi', '2022-01-15', 7),
  ('jkl', '2022-01-15', 6),
  ('mno', '2022-01-15', 5)
  ;
```

Query:

```
WITH max_date AS (
  SELECT *, 
      DATE_TRUNC('month', MAX(search_date) OVER ()) 
          + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day' as max_date
  FROM test
)
SELECT 
  ASIN
, SUM(
      CASE WHEN search_date BETWEEN max_date - interval '12 months' 
          AND max_date
      THEN all_searches 
      ELSE 0 END) jan_ttm_searches
FROM max_date
WHERE search_date BETWEEN '2022-01-31'::date - interval '12 months' 
    AND '2022-01-31'::date
GROUP BY 1
ORDER by 1;
```

SQL Fiddle for play with if you like:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3e0e2/13

Like I said this isn't likely the exact result you are looking for but should get you started.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an example? I tried a CTE using `(SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) -1 AS difference)`, thinking I could put that in the CASE WHEN, but it wouldn't run.

Comment: Thank you...I appreciate the help, but unfortunately this threw an error for me. "Interval values with month or year parts are not supported." I'll keep trying.

Comment: Oh well.  Getting Postgres and Redshift to run the same SQL is a challenge.  You'll need to change these from interval to dateadd().  Same operation, different syntax.